# Django и RoR. Что и чем лучше другого?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

Все свои веб приложения, до настоящего момента, я разрабатывал на PHP. Я понимал, что PHP - язык, мягко говоря, "не ахти", но мне он нравился своей простотой, популярностью и, главное, поддерживанием его любым хостингом.

С новыми навыками приходят и новые возможности, следовательно, кроме PHP нужно знать что-то еще. Я хотел как-то однажды начать изучать Python фреймворк Django, но остановился лишь на изучении самого языка. Язык знаю не плохо, но, если бы не существование не менее популярного веб фреймворка Ruby on Rails, то этого бы вопроса не было, т.к не возникло бы неопределенности...

Так вот, какие у вас мнения по этому поводу?  RoR или Django ? Что и чем лучше другого? Есть ли явные преимущества?

Answer (score 2):

Каждый кулик своё болото хвалит. Проблем и крутотенюшек хватает по обе стороны барикад.
Когда начинал, то исходил из понятности языка и выбрал руби.

Лично для меня он показался понятнее и я тратил меньше времени на то чтобы прочитать исходник и понять что там просиходит.

Но это не значит, что я не смогу написать быструю сортировку на питоне.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему мнению, сейчас на разных сайтах фрилансеров больше заказов на RoR, чем на Django.

Python в связке с Django очень часто используют для не совсем стандартных проектов с нестандартными задачами, где нужно юзать обкатанную машинерию разных питоновских библиотек (Pandas к примеру). Хотя Вам никто не мешает также писать на нем сайты-визитки, магазины, блоги...

ПС: сам использую Django и не жалуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что не много найдётся тех, кто имеют одинаковый уровень на RoR и Django, чтобы беспристрастно Вам ответить. 
В Ruby есть соглашения, которые напрочь отметают вопрос "как лучше сделать", в Python же есть Дзен, и куча сторонних библиотек, не связанных с Web. Как отметил @Hunting, тот же Pandas, NumPy, что в свете тренда DeepLearning, даёт, как я считаю, определённую потенциальную выгоду Django. Для примера, есть [такое](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas) и [такое](https://github.com/wq/django-rest-pandas), но надо понимать, что так просто в DL без особой подготовки делать нечего. Но если хочется замутить с друзьями какой-то стартап в этом направлении, и данные демонстрировать в вэбе, то Django, ИМХО, будет актуальнее.

Вообще, документация и того и другого вызубривается за несколько недель. Если у Вас достаточный опыт в PHP, то не составит проблемы разобраться в обоих фреймворках. Тем более, что вы не обременены предыдущим опытом работы с одним из них.

Что касается экосистем, то тут, думаю, всё более-менее равнозначно.